# Filter and Replace in Different Column

Tags: vba, filter, find

I have some data in the following format:

Table 1, 65,000 rows:

```
Food          Type
Mango         Fruit
Mango         Fruit
Mango         Vegetable
Pineapple     Fruit
Cabbage       Flower
Carrot        Fruit
```

etc, with many columns, where the "Type" column might be incorrect.

Therefore, I would like to correct the "Type" column from another different data set which has correct type mappings:

Table 2, 3000 rows:

```
Food      Type
Cabbage   Vegetable
Carrot    Vegetable
Mango     Fruit
```

etc.

I am trying to update the "Type" data in Table 1 with the "Type" from Table 2.

Normally, in MATLAB or R, I would use vector notations which would be quite fast. Manually, I would use VLOOKUP() which is also not slow, but I would like to remove this manual process.

I can't seem to get it to be fast in VBA for Excel. Double loops are obviously not an option, so I thought I'd use the following approach:

```
Worksheets(Table1).Activate
For index = 2 To lastType    'For loop that goes from row 2 to last row of Table2


    'Filter for the rows we need    
    With Range("A1")
        .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Worksheets(Table2).Cells(index, 1).Value
    End With


    'Update the value of column 2, Table1 with the corresponding value from column 2, Table2
    Range("A2:A" & lastData).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Offset(0, 1).Value = Worksheets(Table2).Cells(index, 2).Value

    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
Next index
```

Any more efficient approach suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out VLOOKUP is not too slow.  Perhaps you could change the formula of each of the cells to be a VLOOKUP.  The Code below will probably need to be modified slightly for your specific ranges but should work nicely.

```
Sub fixtable1()

Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim row As Excel.Range
Dim cell As Excel.Range

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A2")
lngLastRow = rng.End(xlDown).row
lastRowTxt = "B" & lngLastRow

Set rng = Worksheets(1).Range("A2:" & lastRowTxt)

i = 2
For Each row In rng.Rows

    row.Cells(1, 2).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & i & ", Table2!$A$2:$B$5, 2, FALSE)"

    'First loop B2 = "=VLOOKUP(A2, Table2!$A$2:$B$5, 2, FALSE)"
    i = i + 1

Next

End Sub
```

Of course based on your post you will likely change "Table2!$A$2:$B$5" to "Table2!A$2:$B$3001"